# Print ArrayList Object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created several objects and I want to print only one parameter of the objects in ArrayList:

```
Superhero batman = new Superhero("Bruce", 26, "Batman");
Human rachel = new Human("Rachel", 24);

Superhero ironman = new Superhero("Tony", 35, "Ironman");
Human pepper = new Human("Pepper", 22);

List<Human> people = new ArrayList<Human>();
people.add(batman);
people.add(rachel);
people.add(ironman);
people.add(pepper);
```

I want to print:

```
Bruce
Rachel
Tony
Pepper
```

Comment: Iterate over persons in list (access each single person in each iteration), for each person get its name and print it. Ask more specific question about this solution if you have problem with it.

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this with your question.

Comment: To go off of what Pshemo said iterate through the people list, and get the objects name.  `for( Human human : people ) { System.out.println( human.getName() ); }`

Comment: In the future, please show your best good-faith attempt with your question -- else we won't know what you're doing wrong, else your question reads like a beg for code.

Comment: Sorry I'll next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(Human human : people) {
    System.out.println(human.getName());
}
```

This should print name for each human in people list. You should have method in Human class:

```
getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before Java 8

```
for (Human human : people) {
    System.out.println(human.getName());
}
```

Starting from Java 8

```
people.stream().map(Human::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
```